# How to choose columns with only NAs and a unique value and fill NA's with that value?

Tags: r

I have a data frame some columns of which have only a unique value or NA. I want to choose these columns and fill the NA's in these columns with the unique non-missing variable in the column.

Here is a mock-data:

```
df = data.frame( A = c(1,NA,1,1,NA), B = c(2,NA,5,2,5), C =c(3,3,NA,NA,NA))
#df
#   A  B   C
#1  1  2   3
#2  NA NA  3
#3  1  5   NA
#4  1  2   NA
#5  NA 5   NA
```

I want to obtain:

```
#df
#   A B   C
#1  1 2   3
#2  1 NA  3
#3  1 5   3
#4  1 2   3
#5  1 5   3
```

So far, I tried:

```
df = df %>% 
      map_if((length(unique(na.omit(.)))== 1), ~ unique(na.omit(.)))

df = df %>% 
     mutate_if((length(unique(na.omit(.)))== 1), ~ unique(na.omit(.)))
```

Both gave the following error:

> Error in probe(.x, .p) : length(.p) == length(.x) is not TRUE

Can somebody please tell me what is the correct syntax to achieve what I want?

Comment: I am getting the same exact error with this code as well. I think the problem is in the conditional statement: `length(unique(na.omit(.)))== 1)`.  I get the same error when i use this statement in other functions as well (for instance `select_if`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could check for condition in `mutate_if` and if it is satsfied then use the first non-NA value for entire column

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate_if(~n_distinct(.[!is.na(.)]) == 1, funs(.[!is.na(.)][1]))


#  A  B C
#1 1  2 3
#2 1 NA 3
#3 1  5 3
#4 1  2 3
#5 1  5 3
```

which could also be written as suggested by @RHertel

```
df %>% mutate_if(~n_distinct(.[na.omit(.)]) == 1, funs(na.omit(.)[1]))
```

---

To make it more clear we could create functions and use them accordingly

```
only_one_unique <- function(x) {
   n_distinct(x[!is.na(x)]) == 1
}

first_non_NA_value <- function(x) {
   x[!is.na(x)][1]
}

df %>%  mutate_if(only_one_unique, first_non_NA_value)
```

---

We could keep everything in base R using the same logic

```
only_one_unique <- function(x) {
   length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) == 1
}

first_non_NA_value <- function(x) {
   x[!is.na(x)][1]
}

df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) if (only_one_unique(x)) 
                                   first_non_NA_value(x) else x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I misunderstood your question, but is this not just a matter of `fill`?

```
df %>% fill(A, C)
#  A B C
#1 1 2 3
#2 1 4 3
#3 1 5 3
#4 1 2 3
#5 1 5 3
```

To fill *all* columns, and to also make sure that columns starting with an `NA` are filled, we can fill values in both directions (up and down):

```
df %>% fill(everything()) %>% fill(everything(), .direction = "down")
```

---

### Update

Now that I understood your question, we can use `mutate_if` with your conditional statement to `replace` values

```
df %>%
    mutate_if(
        function(x) length(unique(na.omit(x))) == 1,
        function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), unique(na.omit(x))))
#  A  B C
#1 1  2 3
#2 1 NA 3
#3 1  5 3
#4 1  2 3
#5 1  5 3
```

Comment: It might be! I did not know about this function, I am not really an advanced user. Is there a way to not refer A and C by their name? I want to choose all the columns with only one non-missing value and I don't want to search for them  in a data of 300+ columns...

Comment: As my comment to @Moody_Mudskipper above suggests,  I think the problem is in the conditional statement: `length(unique(na.omit(.)))== 1)`

Comment: To fill *all* columns you can simply `df %>% fill(everything())`; I'll make an edit to my post.

Comment: I understand, but I do not want to fill _all_ the columns, I believe I explained it in the question but maybe it wasn't clear. I want to fill the columns which have _only 1 non-missing value_. For instance if there was an NA in B's second row, I wouldn't want it to be filled. Perhaps I should have given a reproducible example including a column with NA's and more than 1 non-missing values.

Comment: @ElifCansuAkoğuz Ok, I understand now. Thanks for clarifying. In that case you're right, `fill` is not the way to go. I'd recommend revising your sample data though to make it more representative of your actual (larger) dataset.

Comment: @ElifCansuAkoğuz I've added a solution using `mutate_if` that should do what you're after. Please take a look.